# R - Assign a value/factor in a data.frame to column conditioned on value(s) of other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, assign

```
set.seed(8)
df <- data.frame(n = rnorm(5,1), m = rnorm(5,0), l = factor(LETTERS[1:5]))
```

Have can I make a new column in `df` conditioned on values or combination of values of n, m and l. 
For instance make a vector `level` and assign it `low`, `medium` and `high` based on values of both `n` and `m` (pseudo-code):

```
df$level <- ifelse(df$n < 1 & df$m < 1, "low", ifelse(df$n > 1 & df$m > 1, "high", "medium")
```

This should give:

```
df$level

#low medium low low medium
```

Or if I would like to assign a value to `level` based on the `l` column and a value in `n` (again, pseudo-code):

```
df$level <- ifelse(df$n < 1 & df$l == c("A", "B"), "low A/B", "high").
```

In this case one should get:

```
df$level

#"low A/B" "high" "high" "high" "high"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do:

```
 c("high", "medium", "low")[rowSums(df[,-3] <1)+1]
#[1] "low"    "medium" "low"    "low"    "medium"

c("high", "low A/B")[(df$n <1 &grepl("A|B", df$l)) +1]
#[1] "low A/B" "high"    "high"    "high"    "high"
```

#### Explanation

- `df[,-3]` gets the subset of numeric columns i.e. `n` and `m`
- `df[,-3] <1` gives a logical index of `TRUE`, `FALSE` if the element is `<1` or not.
- By doing `rowSums` on the above, it gives three possible values - 0, 1, 2 based on whether the corresponding values in each row are both >1, one value <1, and both <1.

  ```
  rowSums(df[,-3] <1) #in this example, there are no values equal to 0
  #[1] 2 1 2 2 1
  ```
- `+1` to the above will give us

  ```
  rowSums(df[,-3] <1) +1
  #[1] 3 2 3 3 2
  ```
- Using the above as numeric index, we can do:

  ```
    c("high", "medium", "low")[rowSums(df[,-3] <1)+1]
    #[1] "low"    "medium" "low"    "low"    "medium"
  ```
- `low` will occupy the places of numeric value `3`, `medium` on `2` and if there was 1, `high` should occupy that.

Comment: Could on explain this syntax (as also in Sven's solution); im not sure I get the c(...)[....]. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution:

```
df$level1 <- c("low", "medium", "high")[rowMeans(sign(df[c("n", "m")] - 1)) + 2]

df$level2 <- c("high", "low A/B")[(df$n < 1 & df$l %in% c("A", "B")) + 1]

#           n          m l level1  level2
# 1 0.9154139 -0.1078814 A    low low A/B
# 2 1.8404001 -0.1702891 B medium    high
# 3 0.5365172 -1.0883317 C    low    high
# 4 0.4491650 -3.0110517 D    low    high
# 5 1.7360404 -0.5931743 E medium    high
```

Comment: Yeah it does the job fine. But I was sort of hoping for a more 'general' way to make such conditional assigning values ? What if level1 was not <1 for n and m, but, say <0.4 in n and <1.3 in m ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably missing the question, but when I add a **missing closing parenthesis**, it seems to work just fine:

```
> df$level <- ifelse(df$n < 1 & df$m < 1, "low", ifelse(df$n > 1 & df$m > 1, "high", "medium"))
> df
          n          m l  level
1 0.9154139 -0.1078814 A    low
2 1.8404001 -0.1702891 B medium
3 0.5365172 -1.0883317 C    low
4 0.4491650 -3.0110517 D    low
5 1.7360404 -0.5931743 E medium
> df$level
[1] "low"    "medium" "low"    "low"    "medium"
```

Answer (score 0):

More of an extended comment than an answer, and perhaps not exactly what you're looking for.

Usually, when I need to capture groups of continuous variables and convert them to a single categorical variable, I use clustering and title the clusters according to the values presented. Here's an example using kmeans:

```
set.seed(8)
df <- data.frame(n = rnorm(5000,1), m = rnorm(5000,0), l = factor(LETTERS[1:5]))
df$Category <- kmeans(df[1:2],7)$cluster

kmeans(df[1:2],7)
K-means clustering with 7 clusters of sizes 593, 606, 649, 626, 641, 1219, 666

Cluster means:
           n           m
1 -0.2097451  0.84837728 # Low-High
2  1.0977826  1.44383531 # Mid-Upper
3  2.1682482 -0.70983193 # High-Low
4 -0.3389432 -0.54514302 # Low-Low
5  2.3332772  0.67415808 # High-Mid
6  0.9816709 -0.01549909 # Upper-Mid
7  0.8859904 -1.46126667 # Mid-Low

df$Category <- factor(df$Category, c("Low-High","Mid-Upper","High-Low","Low-Low",...))
```

You would have to look at the mean results of the clusters on your own computer (with seed) to be able to label them appropriately. This will also provide you with groupings based on your data rather than an arbitrary threshold that you believe is correct for your data.