# R - Normalise column groups based on column names and add column with conditional value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm new to R and `dplyr` (coming from a pandas/python background) and am currently trying to do more data manipulation in R. The `dplyr` syntax has really grown on me, but working on my current data normalisation I can't help but think "there must be a 'cleaner' way of doing it".

I have two `data.frames`, the first has values which I'd like to use to dynamically normalise subsets of the second. I then want to average all columns which have names that end identically, then group and classify rows by the higher/lower means. If this was too unclear, I hope the code clears some things up.

#### Normalisation (works, but messy?)

```
> main
  airport location x1.takeoffs x1.landings x2.takeoffs x2.landings x3.takeoffs x3.landings x4.takeoffs x4.landings
1     YYZ     N.A.      301029      300976      291615      291614      259649      259613       40326       40297
2     LHR     U.K.      211013      210983      360456      360389      241972      241964      309509      309495
3     JFK     N.A.      432521      432491      205626      205592     1877087     1877060      865802      865771
4     MUC     E.U.      101023      101011       43562       43509      234134      234071       30110       30087
5     VIE     E.U.      250102      250079      128620      128561      152017      152015     1418485     1418471

> norm
  name counts
1   x1     10
2   x2     20
3   x3     30
4   x4     40
```

What I'd like to do is take all columns that start with `x1`, and divide them by `norm[which(norm$name == "x1"),]$counts`, and so on for `x2`, `x3`, and `x4`.

Here's my code:

```
mainNorm <- main
for (n in norm$name) {
    mainNorm[grep(n, colnames(mainNorm))] <- main %>%
        select(starts_with(n)) %>%
        mutate_each(funs(. / norm[which(norm$name == n),]$counts))
}
```

Now I average all `.takeoffs` and `.landings`:

```
mainNorm <- mainNorm %>%
  mutate(avg.takeoff=select(., ends_with(".takeoffs")) %>%
  rowMeans(na.rm=T))
mainNorm <- mainNorm %>%
  mutate(avg.landings=select(., ends_with(".landings")) %>%
  rowMeans(na.rm=T))
```

#### Dynamic column assignment based on min/max of other column

Last, I would like to add a new column, which looks at `location` groups and assigns either `"high"`, or `"low"` based on the value in `avg.takeoff`

I've been trying the `rowSums` approach suggested in a different question ( [R - Assign a value/factor in a data.frame to column conditioned on value(s) of other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287285/r-assign-a-value-factor-in-a-data-frame-to-column-conditioned-on-values-of-o) ) but am hitting a bit of a wall.

```
> mainNorm %>%
    group_by(location) %>%
    mutate(volume=c("high", "low")[rowSums(select(., avg.takeoff) <1)+1])
Error: Position must be between 0 and n
```

---

#### TL;DR

So, in summary my questions are:

1. Is there a more `dplyr`ish way around the for loop? I wouldn't mind `melt`in the data from `norm` in to `main` if that helps?
2. How do I assign `"low"` and `"high"` in the `group_by` call? I'm guessing I'll have to pass it to a custom function?

Regarding my second question I'm guessing this always would be an option:

```
mainNorm %>%
  group_by(location) %>%
  filter(avg.takeoff == min(avg.takeoff)) %>%
  mutate(volume="low")
```

But if I now want to handle the other half of the data I'd have to repeat, and then join the two tables. Is there a way of doing this in a single `filter` call? (Back to functions, I guess?)

---

#### Edit: Exptected result

Incorporating @alistair's suggestion helped, but I'm still unsure about the last part: assigning `"high"`, `"low"`. What I'd like to end up with (in some shape or form) is the following table:

```
# A tibble: 40 × 9
   airport location  name variable value_norm counts avg.takeoff avg.landings volume
    <fctr>   <fctr> <chr>    <chr>      <dbl>  <int>       <dbl>        <dbl> <fctr>
1      YYZ     N.A.    x1 takeoffs    30102.9     10   13586.692    13584.873    low
2      LHR     U.K.    x1 takeoffs    21101.3     10   13731.890    13730.148   high
3      JFK     N.A.    x1 takeoffs    43252.1     10   34437.000    34435.410   high
4      MUC     E.U.    x1 takeoffs    10102.3     10    5209.404     5207.773    low
5      VIE     E.U.    x1 takeoffs    25010.2     10   17992.640    17991.220   high
6      YYZ     N.A.    x1 landings    30097.6     10   13586.692    13584.873    low
7      LHR     U.K.    x1 landings    21098.3     10   13731.890    13730.148   high
8      JFK     N.A.    x1 landings    43249.1     10   34437.000    34435.410   high
9      MUC     E.U.    x1 landings    10101.1     10    5209.404     5207.773    low
10     VIE     E.U.    x1 landings    25007.9     10   17992.640    17991.220   high
# ... with 30 more rows
```

Comment: Your data is in an untidy form, which is why you're forced to resort to such convolutions. Tidy it first, and the calculations become simple: `library(tidyverse); main %>% gather(variable, value, matches('x\\d')) %>% separate(variable, c('name', 'variable')) %>% left_join(norm) %>% mutate(value_norm = value / counts)`. If you want a full answer, post your desired results.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Averaging now is much more readable with `group_by(airport, variable) %>% summarise(avg = mean(value_norm))`. I've added the desired output in an edit.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the high and low is based on. ("based on the value in `avg.takeoff`" isn't very specific, is what I mean).

Comment: Perhaps just `mutate(volume = ifelse(avg.takeoff == min(avg.takeoff), "low", "high"))`?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. In pseudo-code, what I'd like is:

Comment: I'd like to assign either low or high volume traffic, based on their average takeoffs, within the location groups. I think the `ifelse` approach should work nicely.
I'll piece it together and add it above.